# how to convert all the values in a list into keys of a Dictionary in Py2.7

Tags: python-2.7

I've below lists,

```
lists=[ ['arya','egg','milk','butter','bread'],
        ['Jon','butter','pastrie','yogurt','beer'],
        ['bran','beer','milk','banana','apples'],]
```

Each list has values in which the first value is the name of a person and 
rest of all are some food items.
 
 I've a task where I've to create a dictionary with these food items as keys and the person as a value as shown below

```
    dict = { 'egg' : set(['arya']),
             'milk': set(['arya','bran']),
             'butter' : set(['arya','jon']),
             'bread' : set(['arya']),
             'pastrie' : set(['jon']),
              'milk' : set(['bran'])
             }                         # few keys omitted
```

This is what I did and stopped, dont know how to proceed further,

```
food,person = [],[]

for i in lists:
    food.append(i[1:])
    person.append(i[0])
```

I was able to seperate the first value of each list and append it to a list
and same with food.
Dont know how to proceed further. 
started learning python, Any input is highly helpful. kindly share one or two lines of explanation to enlighten this newbie !

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Using dictionary method [setdefault](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict) is helpful here.

You of course don't nee to set the slices to a variable, but it makes it easier to read.

```
d = {}
for l in lists:
    name = l[0]
    items = l[1:]
    for item in items:
        d.setdefault(item, set()).add(name)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `collections.defaultdict`:

```
lists = [['arya', 'egg', 'milk', 'butter', 'bread'],
     ['Jon', 'butter', 'pastrie', 'yogurt', 'beer'],
     ['bran', 'beer', 'milk', 'banana', 'apples']]

from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(set)
for sub in lists:
    for v in sub[1:]:
       d[v].add(sub[0])


print(d)
```

Output:

```
defaultdict(<class 'set'>,
 {'bread': {'arya'}, 'yogurt': {'Jon'}, 'beer': {'Jon', 'bran'}, 
'banana': {'bran'}, 'butter': {'Jon', 'arya'}, 'milk': {'arya', 
'bran'}, 'pastrie': {'Jon'}, 'egg': {'arya'}, 'apples': {'bran'}})
```

For python3 the syntax is a little nicer:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(set)
for name, *rest in lists:
    for v in rest:
       d[v].add(name)
```